# Where does Bungou Stray Dogs cut off in the manga?

Tags: bungou-stray-dogs

I have watched *Bungou Stray Dogs* and now, I want to start reading the manga because there is no announcement about a new season. So, in which chapter should I start for the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Mangaupdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=87668),

> Season 1 ended at **Vol. 4 Chapter 16**, Season 2 ended at **Vol. 9 Chapter 37**, and Season 3 ended at **Vol. 13 Chapter 53**.